# Como verificar entrada de horário e anular cálculo quando vier em branco

Tags: php, datetime

Estou calculando a diferença entre dois horários usando [datetime](/questions/tagged/datetime), mas quando um horário não é preenchido preciso que ele não faça cálculo nenhum (o resultado precisa ser `0` ou `NULL`), mas ele calcula considerando 00:00.

Então se por exemplo o campo final foi preenchido com 07:00, e o outro não foi preenchido, ele não devia calcular nada, mas mesmo assim ele acusa uma diferença de 7 horas. Ou se for o contrário, contabiliza 17 horas...

O formulário:

```
<label class="form-inline" for="Cseg3">Horário 1:
<input type="text" id="Cseg3" name="Tsegs" class="form-control horario tempo linha1"></label>

<label class="form-inline" for="Cseg4">Horário 2:
<input type="text" id="Cseg4" name="Tsegss" class="form-control horario tempo linha1"></label>
```

Pega os dados do formulário:

```
$val1 = isset($_POST["Tsegs"]) ? $_POST["Tsegs"] : NULL;
$val2 = isset($_POST["Tsegss"]) ? $_POST["Tsegss"] : NULL;
```

Converte para [dateinterval](/questions/tagged/dateinterval):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2017-04-05, $val1");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2017-05-06, $val2");
```

Encontrando a diferença:

```
$intervalo = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

Transforma os objetos em variáveis:

```
$horario1 = $intervalo->h; // DIFERENÇA EM HORAS (INT)
$horario2 = $intervalo->i; // PEGA OS MINUTOS
```

Já tentei pegar os dados do formulário com algumas variações de `isset`e `empty`, tipo:

```
$val1 = isset($_POST["Tsegs"]) ? $_POST["Tsegs"] : NULL;

$val1 = empty($_POST["Tsegs"]) ? NULL : $_POST["Tsegs"];
```

Mas ele sempre considera 00:00. Um `var_dump` de `$val1` retorna (quando não preenchido):

> string(0) ""

Então a pergunta é: Como faço pra que quando um campo não for preenchido, ele não realizar o cálculo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você tem que fazer a verificação antes de fazer tudo. Tipo:

```
//se for diferente de null, faz o calculo
if ($val1 <> null and $val2 <> null) {

$datetime1 = new DateTime("2017-04-05, $val1");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2017-05-06, $val2");
$horario1 = $intervalo->h; // DIFERENÇA EM HORAS (INT)
$horario2 = $intervalo->i; // PEGA OS MINUTOS 
}
```

se um dos dois for igual a NULL ele não faz nada.

Comment: Parece uma boa ideia mesmo, vou testar aqui... +1